# Verilog to VHDL conversion

Tags: verilog, vhdl

I have the following piece of code in Verilog which I am trying to convert to VHDL.

Verilog code:

```
always@(posedge iGO or negedge iRST)
begin
    if(!iRST)
        go_en   <=  0;
    else
    begin
        if(iGO)
            go_en   <=  1;
    end
end
```

VHDL conversion:

```
50. process (iGO, iRST)
51. begin
52.  if falling_edge(iRST) then
53.   if (iRST = '0') then
54.     go_en <= '0';
55.   elsif rising_edge(iGO) then
56.     go_en <= '1';
57.   end if;
58.  end if;
59. end process;
```

I am getting the following errors.

```
Error (10820): Netlist error at adc_control.vhd(52): can't infer register for go_en because its behavior depends on the edges of multiple distinct clocks
Info (10041): Inferred latch for "go_en" at adc_control.vhd(50)
Error (10822): HDL error at adc_control.vhd(52): couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge
Error (10822): HDL error at adc_control.vhd(55): couldn't implement registers for assignments on this clock edge
```

How do I fix these errors?

Comment: The trick is to recognise that the Reset input on a flip-flop is level sensitive, not edge sensitive. So remove the outer IF statement entirely. (Synthesis style guides will show this style, level sensitive reset, edge sensitive clock, if you need more information.

Comment: This code works fine in Verilog. I am able to compile without any issues and also see the LEDs blinking in the evaluation board.

Comment: I am using Quartus Prime Lite Edition and the hardware is the DE0-NANO board which has an Cyclone IV EP4CE22F17C6N FPGA and a 12-bit A to D converter. The DE0-NANO board comes with a CD which has an example A to D converter code in Verilog which is what I am trying to convert to VHDL.

Comment: See [Positive edge reset and negative edge reset](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/597810/positive-edge-reset-and-negative-edge-reset) which agrees with user188839 and gives you something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVfAr.jpg).

Comment: http://cwcserv.ucsd.edu/~billlin/classes/ECE111/lectures/Lecture3.pdf See pages 6 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

Your VHDL code is not totally equivalent to the Verilog. If we denote `X+` and `X-` the rising and falling edges of signal `X` the Verilog code can be rewritten as the following pseudo code:

```
if iGO+ or iRST- {
  if iRST == 0 {
    go_en <- 0
  } elsif iGO == 1 {
    go_en <- 1
  }
}
```

By considering that:

- if there was a falling edge of `X` then `X == 0`,
- and if `iRST != 0` then there must have been a rising edge of `iGO`,

we can reformulate as the equivalent:

```
if iGO+ or iRST- {
  if iRST == 0 {
    go_en <- 0
  } elsif iGO+ {
    go_en <- 1
  }
}
```

Your VHDL code is more or less equivalent to:

```
if iGO+ or iGO- or iRST+ or iRST- {
  if iRST- {
    if iRST == 0 {
      go_en <- 0
    } elsif iGO+ {
      go_en <- 1
    }
  }
}
```

By considering again that if there was a falling edge of `X` then `X == 0` we can rewrite as the equivalent:

```
if iRST- {
  go_en <- 0
}
```

This is not the same. Moreover you are using two signal edges to trigger your logic in the same process. This is not supported by all synthesizers and/or hardware targets, reason why you get these errors.

As noted in comments the important aspect to consider is that `iRST` is not another clock but an asynchronous active low reset. The VHDL equivalent is:

```
process(iGO, iRST)
begin
  if iRST = '0' then
    go_en <= '0';
  elsif rising_edge(iGO) then
    go_en <= '1';
  end if;
end process;
```